Program always enters the first if-statement
No matter what letter I input, it gives me the first option, I'm looking for the error but I'm new, 3 days learning so far, so I honestly don't see it and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
In case anyone wants to know what course I'm doing it's this one.
Here is the code that has the problem:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Pack { 
    double Price;
    char Package; 
};

int main() {


Pack Basic;
Basic.Price = 29.99;
Basic.Package = 'A';

Pack Essential;
Essential.Price = 39.99;
Essential.Package = 'B';

Pack Premium;
Premium.Price = 49.99;
Premium.Package = 'C';

Pack Advance;
Advance.Price = 89.99;
Advance.Package = 'D';

Pack Ultimate;
Ultimate.Price = 199.99;
Ultimate.Package = 'E';

Pack PremiumFam;
PremiumFam.Price = 69.99;
PremiumFam.Package = 'F';

Pack AdvanceFam;
AdvanceFam.Price = 89.99;
AdvanceFam.Package = 'G';

Pack UltimateFam;
UltimateFam.Price = 249.99;
UltimateFam.Package = 'H';


cout << "McAfee Package refund % Multiplier" "\n\n";

cout<< "This program will allow you to get the refund % of any packages" "\n" "Please see Packages below: " "\n\n";
cout<< "A- Basic $29.99" "\n" "B- Essential $39.99 " "\n\n";
cout<< "C- Premium: $49.99" "\n" "D- Advance (Individual) $89.99" "\n" "E- Ultimate (Individual) $199.99" "\n\n";
cout<< "F- Premium (Family) $69.99" "\n" "G- Advance (Family) $69.99" "\n" "H- Ultimate (Family) $249.99" "\n\n";

char Intro;

cout<< "Please select the package by letter assigned: " "\n";
cin>> Intro;

if (Intro = Basic.Package) {
cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Basic" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << Basic.Price;
} else if (Intro = Essential.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Essential" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << Essential.Price;
} else if (Intro = Premium.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Premium" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << Premium.Price;
} else if (Intro = Advance.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Advance (Individual)" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << Advance.Price;
} else if (Intro = Ultimate.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Ultimate (Individual)" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << Ultimate.Price;
} else if (Intro = PremiumFam.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Premium (Family)" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << PremiumFam.Price;
} else if (Intro = AdvanceFam.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Advance (Family)" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << AdvanceFam.Price;
} else {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Ultimate (Family)" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << UltimateFam.Price;
}

return 0; }


This has got to be answered somewhere here. In your if statements you're using the = assignment operator when you should be using the == comparison operator. Check also that you're comparing case properly. a != A.

What seems strange to me is that you're learning about struct, but didn't learn how to write simple if statements to check for equality.  The latter should have been learned way before the former, as you cannot properly write any C++ program that asks "is this value equal to another value?".

You could eliminate this issue by using switch, or maybe a std::vector or std::map.

You have missed a equal to symbol
if (Intro == Basic.Package) {
cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Basic" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << Basic.Price;
} else if (Intro == Essential.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Essential" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << Essential.Price;
} else if (Intro == Premium.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Premium" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << Premium.Price;
} else if (Intro == Advance.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Advance (Individual)" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << Advance.Price;
} else if (Intro == Ultimate.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Ultimate (Individual)" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << Ultimate.Price;
} else if (Intro == PremiumFam.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Premium (Family)" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << PremiumFam.Price;
} else if (Intro == AdvanceFam.Package) {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Advance (Family)" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << AdvanceFam.Price;
} else {
    cout<< "The Package selected is: " << "Ultimate (Family)" << "\t" << "At a cost of: $" << UltimateFam.Price;
}

Intro == Basic.Package this is the part you have missed
if you gave it like Intro = Basic.package it assigns the Intro as Basic.package value which it contains Thats the issue you got same error
